# Angular 4 Material table wont compile: Unexpected closing tag

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am working on a Angluar 4 Project with Material. I am trying to implement a table from Angular Material. The Problem is that the table wont compile.

Html:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

  <ng-container matColumnDef "name">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let project">{{project.name}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef "key">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Key </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let project">{{project.Key}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef "reason">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> reason </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let project">{{project.reason}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; column: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>

</mat-table>
```

DataSource:

```
  export class ProjectDataSource extends DataSource<any>{
constructor(private project:ProjectComponent){
  super();
}

connect(): Observable<Project[]>{
return this.project.returnDeadProjectList();
}

disconnect(){}
```

I dont think the problem has to do with the DataSouce. But still i am converting an array to an Observable in the `returnDeadProjectList()` that contains multiple objects. When I load the page the array is still empty but it should still work.

Error message:
`compiler.js:466 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "ng-container". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("me </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let project">{{project.name}}</mat-cell>
      [ERROR ->]</ng-container>`

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing ,

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
```

similarly,

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="key">
```

etc

Updated HTML with fix:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let project">{{project.name}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="key">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Key </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let project">{{project.Key}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="reason">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> reason </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let project">{{project.reason}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; column: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>

</mat-table>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean with missing?

Comment: you are missing the = sign

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped. But now i am getting a new error:

compiler.js:466 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'matRowDefColumn' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-row'.
1. If 'mat-row' is an Angular component and it has 'matRowDefColumn' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-row' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

Comment: make sure you are importing MatTableModule from @angular/materia

Comment: I am importing it. Do i need to import anything else? Its kind of wierd, i dont even use an element that has this name.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for your new error:

`mat-row` element's `*matRowDef` should be `project` but you didn't change that one. That's why you getting that error.

Your code:

```
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; column: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
```

Updated code:

```
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let project; column: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
```

Comment: my data source is 
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);

const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
  {position: 1, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', email: 'john@gmail.com'},
  {position: 1, firstName: 'Mike', lastName: 'Hussey', email: 'mike@gmail.com'},
  {position: 1, firstName: 'Ricky', lastName: 'Hans', email: 'ricky@gmail.com'}
];

and the html code is

<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; column: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>